# NuSOAP - create server with the authentication

Tags: c#, php, soap, nusoap

I've created WebService using NuSoap library, but I can't find anywhere how to implement authentication. 
Basically what I want is to connect to this service from C# and add NetworkCredential with the username and password.

```
userdatawsdl d = new userdatawsdl();
d.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");
val = d.GetUserData("x");
```

So basically what I need to do in php script in order to accept this data and automatically authenticate client request.

This is how my php script looks like now, I have excluded methods which are registered

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

// create the server object
$server = new soap_server;

// Initialize WSDL support
$server->configureWSDL('userdatawsdl', 'urn:userdatawsdl');

// register soap functions
$server->register('GetUserData', array('memberNumber' => 'xsd:string'), array('result' => 'xsd:string'));
$server->register('GetUserStatus', array('memberNumber' => 'xsd:string'), array('result' => 'xsd:string'));

if (isset($error))
{
    $fault =
            $server->fault('soap:Server','',$error);
}

// send the result as a SOAP response over HTTP
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.funphp.com/?p=49): it covers implementing authentication in a SOAP server with NuSOAP, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I have already tried that it doesn't work, I have copied code and tried to create new WS but nothing, it doesn't work, and also I have googled everything, every combination...

Comment: Ah. Well, looking at the code you have above I can't tell that: can you post your complete code that includes the validation functions you are trying to use?

Comment: That is my real code, I'm asking how can I implement authentication in it, that is my question.